# Multilevel models in R using nmle package

Tags: r, statistics, nlme

I am using the `nlme` package to learn multilevel models, and following examples from the textbook "Discovering Statistics Using R" when it happened.

[Mixed Models Code](https://studysites.uk.sagepub.com/dsur/study/DSUR%20R%20Script%20Files/Chapter%2019%20DSUR%20Mixed%20Models.R)

The data set is Honeymoon `Period.dat`, also downloadable under their companion website.

[Data Set - Multilevel Models](https://studysites.uk.sagepub.com/dsur/study/articles.htm)

```
require(nlme)
require(reshape2)
satisfactionData = read.delim("Honeymoon Period.dat",  header = TRUE)

restructuredData<-melt(satisfactionData, id = c("Person", "Gender"), measured = c("Satisfaction_Base", "Satisfaction_6_Months", "Satisfaction_12_Months", "Satisfaction_18_Months"))
names(restructuredData)<-c("Person", "Gender", "Time", "Life_Satisfaction")


#print(restructuredData)
#restructuredData.sorted<-restructuredData[order(Person),]

intercept <-gls(Life_Satisfaction~1, data = restructuredData, method = "ML", na.action = na.exclude)
randomIntercept <-lme(Life_Satisfaction ~1, data = restructuredData, random = ~1|Person, method = "ML",  na.action = na.exclude, control = list(opt="optim"))
anova(intercept, randomIntercept)

timeRI<-update(randomIntercept, .~. + Time)
timeRS<-update(timeRI, random = ~Time|Person)
ARModel<-update(timeRS, correlation = corAR1(0, form = ~Time|Person))
```

The error occured at this moment, when I am trying to update "timeRS" model.
The error message is as follows:

> Error in as.character.factor(X[[i]], ...) : malformed factor

Any stats people/programmers here who knows what this means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have looked at this book. It appears that the coding is wrong. The error you are getting is because your time variable is a factor and you need it to be numeric. In the author's first figure in the book he represents time as numeric (0 - 3) but his code for the models is incorrect. I've recoded it for you:

```
## First, Time needs to be recoded as a numeric

restructuredData$Time.Numeric <- with(restructuredData, ifelse(Time == "Satisfaction_Base", 0, 
        ifelse(Time == "Satisfaction_6_Months", 1,
        ifelse(Time == "Satisfaction_12_Months", 2,
        ifelse(Time == "Satisfaction_18_Months", 3, NA)))))

## Baseline Model

intercept <-gls(Life_Satisfaction~1, data = restructuredData, method = "ML", na.action = na.exclude)

summary(intercept)

## Model where intercept can vary for Individuals

randomIntercept <- lme(Life_Satisfaction ~ 1, data = restructuredData, random = ~1|Person, method = "ML", na.action = na.exclude, control = list(opt = "optim"))

summary(randomIntercept)

## Add time as a fixed effect

timeRI <- lme(Life_Satisfaction ~ Time.Numeric, data = restructuredData, random = ~1|Person, method = "ML", na.action = na.exclude, control = list(opt = "optim"))

summary(timeRI)

## Add a random slope to the model by nesting the Individual within the test time

timeRS <- lme(Life_Satisfaction ~ Time.Numeric, data = restructuredData, random = ~Time.Numeric|Person, method = "ML", na.action = na.exclude, control = list(opt = "optim"))

summary(timeRS)


## Modeling the covariance structure structure of the errors with a first-order autoregressive covariance structure

ARModel <- update(timeRS, correlation = corAR1(0, form = ~Time.Numeric|Person))

summary(ARModel)

anova(intercept, randomIntercept, timeRI, timeRS, ARModel)
```

The anova read out for model comparisons is now exactly as shown in the book.

Comment: Good advice! I simplified it a bit: `restructuredData[,"Time"] <- as.numeric(restructuredData[,"Time"]) - 1` This can be run before the first model definition: `intercept <-gls(Life_Satisfaction ~ 1, data = restructuredData, method =
"ML", na.action = na.exclude)` And than the remaining code doesn't need to be changed.